# Error with google app engine:Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I encountered this error while working on a web application for google app engine,through this tutorial.http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html. Would like to hear more advice from you. Thank you.

```
    HTTP ERROR 500

    Problem accessing /. Reason:

        Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 34 in the jsp file: /TodoApplication.jsp
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Todo> to List<Todo>
    31: if (user != null){
    32:     url = userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI());
    33:     urlLinktext = "Logout";
    34:     todos = dao.getTodos(user.getUserId());
    35: }
    36:     
    37: %>


    Stacktrace:
    Caused by:

    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

    An error occurred at line: 34 in the jsp file: /TodoApplication.jsp
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Todo> to List<Todo>
    31: if (user != null){
    32:     url = userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI());
    33:     urlLinktext = "Logout";
    34:     todos = dao.getTodos(user.getUserId());
    35: }
    36:     
    37: %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.User" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserService" %>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.users.UserServiceFactory" %>
<%@ page import="de.vogella.gae.java.todo.model.Todo" %>
<%@ page import="de.vogella.gae.java.todo.dao.Dao" %>
```

TodoApplication.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Todos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
      <meta charset="utf-8"> 
  </head>
  <body>
<%
Dao dao = Dao.INSTANCE;

UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
User user = userService.getCurrentUser();

String url = userService.createLoginURL(request.getRequestURI());
String urlLinktext = "Login";
List<Todo> todos = new ArrayList<Todo>();

if (user != null){
    url = userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI());
    urlLinktext = "Logout";
    todos = dao.getTodos(user.getUserId());
}

%>
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="line"></div>
    <div class="topLine">
      <div style="float: left;"><img src="images/todo.png" /></div>
      <div style="float: left;" class="headline">Todos</div>
      <div style="float: right;"><a href="<%=url%>"><%=urlLinktext%></a> <%=(user==null? "" : user.getNickname())%></div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div style="clear: both;"/>  
You have a total number of <%= todos.size() %>  Todos.

<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Short description </th>
      <th>Long Description</th>
      <th>URL</th>
      <th>Done</th>
    </tr>

<% for (Todo todo : todos) {%>
<tr> 
<td>
<%=todo.getShortDescription()%>
</td>
<td>
<%=todo.getLongDescription()%>
</td>
<td>
<%=todo.getUrl()%>
</td>
<td>
<a class="done" href="/done?id=<%=todo.getId()%>" >Done</a>
</td>
</tr> 
<%}
%>
</table>


<hr />

<div class="main">

<div class="headline">New todo</div>

<% if (user != null){ %> 

<form action="/new" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><label for="summary">Summary</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="summary" id="summary" size="65"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="description"><label for="description">Description</label></td>
      <td><textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" id="description"></textarea></td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><label for="url">URL</label></td>
    <td><input type="url" name="url" id="url" size="65" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" value="Create"/></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>

<% }else{ %>

Please login with your Google account

<% } %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built and ran the very good [Google App Engine Tutorial for Java (Todo list with JPA)](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) with no problems at all.  The platform was GAE SDK 1.8.9, Eclipse 3.8, OpenJDK 7u21 and Debian Testing (jessie).  This result verifies the correctness of all the tutorial source code.  Your problem is somewhere in your local installation.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the instance returned by your dao.getTodos method, is not from a class that implements java.util.List interface.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
34:     todos = dao.getTodos(user.getUserId());
```

clobbers the reference to ArrayList assigned earlier to todos.  Instead try

```
todos.addAll( dao.getTodos(user.getUserId()) );
```

Comment: Dear Martin, thanks for the feedback, still getting error message of     

HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 34 in the jsp file: /TodoApplication.jsp
The method addAll(Collection<? extends Todo>) in the type List<Todo> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Todo>)
31: if (user != null){
32:     url = userService.createLogoutURL(request.getRequestURI());
33:     urlLinktext = "Logout";
34:     todos.addAll( dao.getTodos(user.getUserId()) );
35: }
36:     
37: %>

Comment: Hmm, both your results suggest a subtle kind of type mismatch...  The [tutorial at vogel/a](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GoogleAppEngineJava/article.html) looks well written, I'll replicate your implementation of it after Irish breakfast time...